# is this possible to uninstall rpm package in only one command from list>> grep >> uninstall?

Tags: centos, package-management, rpm

I'm thinking about include 3 steps to uninstall a package on CentOS7 but stuck in merge 3 command of uninstall a package to only 1 command.

Okay, this is my situation: I have java package *jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm* which install successfully before, and I want to uninstall it.
Of course, I can not uninstall this java package using command :

```
# rpm -e jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm
```

So I have to using 3 command in 3 steps as below :

- Step 1: I have to find the name of the package i install by :

  ```
  [susu@localhost ~]$ rpm -qip jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm
  [susu@localhost ~]$ rpm -qip jdk-8u151-linux-x64.rpm
  Name        : jdk1.8
  ```
- Step 2: using this command to find exactly package are:

  ```
  [susu@localhost ~]$ sudo rpm -qa |grep -i 'jdk1.8'
  [sudo] password for susu: 
  jdk1.8-1.8.0_151-fcs.x86_64
  ```
- Step 3: using `rpm -e` to erase the package:

  ```
  rpm -e jdk1.8-1.8.0_151-fcs.x86_64
  ```

So my question is: how can I merge the command in Step 2 and Step 3 into only one command?

Answer (score 1):

Query for the NVR and remove that.

```
rpm -e "$(rpm -qp --queryformat '%{name}-%{version}-%{release}' "$1")"
```